# Laravel fluent query based on data from a subselect query

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying - with laravel 4 to get a query that produces the average number of visitors/customers for each day of the week eg Monday, TUesday, Wednesday etc within a given period.

I can do this in mySql with the following query:

```
SELECT day_of_week, AVG(visitors_sum) average_order FROM 
(
  SELECT DAYNAME(play_date) day_of_week, 
     DAYOFWEEK(play_date) day_num, 
     TO_DAYS(play_date) `date`,
     sum(group_size) visitors_sum
  FROM reservations 
  GROUP BY `date`
) temp
GROUP BY day_of_week 
ORDER BY day_num
```

I tried simply doing a db::raw with the query but that doesnt work. and beyond that I can't qork this out. I tried creating the sub query first with:

```
$average = DB::table('reservations',
        DB::raw('DAYNAME(play_date) AS day_of_week, 
                 DAYOFWEEK(play_date) AS day_num, 
                 TO_DAYS(play_date) AS playdate,
                 sum(group_size) as visitors_sum)'))
        ->groupBy('day_of_week')
        ->get();
```

but that came up with an error unknown column 'day_of_week' so I assume fluent can't support alias in groupBy and presumably sortby?

So, how can I re-create this query to get the results i need, ideally in one call?

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## Laravel doc examples could be a little more detailed

This is a little late for your request, but try this if this could still be of help to you. I was having very similar issues figuring this out in Laravel fluent. One issue I had when rolling everything into a **DB::select** statement is I couldn't use the **->paginate()** method on the results as an object wasn't getting returned. **This code keeps things in a DB object that allows you to use object methods on the results, e.g. ->paginate(), ->toJson, ->toArray, ->toSql** etc.

The **->from()** method used below was only used ONCE on the docs page in an obscure use case that I missed the first 10 times I read over the docs.

#### I have a ->toSql() at the end of this to get the output of the actual SQL code I posted below. You would change this to a **->get()** to retrieve your data.

```
      $average = DB::table('temp')
            ->select(DB::Raw('day_of_week, AVG(visitors_sum) average_order'))
            ->from(DB::Raw('(
                  SELECT DAYNAME(play_date) day_of_week,
                         DAYOFWEEK(play_date) day_num,
                         TO_DAYS(play_date) `date`,
                         sum(group_size) visitors_sum
                  FROM reservations
                  GROUP BY `date`
                ) temp'))
            ->groupBy('temp.day_of_week')
            ->orderBy('temp.day_num')
            ->toSql();
```

This is the actual SQL generated by Laravel 4 fluent from the above code which is pretty much functionally identical to your raw code in the original question.

```
string(457) "select day_of_week, AVG(visitors_sum) average_order from (
                  SELECT DAYNAME(play_date) day_of_week,
                         DAYOFWEEK(play_date) day_num,
                         TO_DAYS(play_date) `date`,
                         sum(group_size) visitors_sum
                  FROM reservations
                  GROUP BY `date`
                ) temp group by `temp`.`day_of_week` order by `temp`.`day_num` asc"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yay - found the results. I was over complicating this and can use the following for the same results:

```
$average = DB::select(
        'SELECT day_of_week, 
        AVG(visitors_sum) average_order 
        FROM 
            (
              SELECT DAYNAME(play_date) day_of_week, 
                     DAYOFWEEK(play_date) day_num, 
                     TO_DAYS(play_date) `date`,
                     sum(group_size) visitors_sum
              FROM reservations 
              GROUP BY `date`
            ) temp
        GROUP BY day_of_week 
        ORDER BY day_num');
```

This gets me the results I need. I thought `Select` needed a table but can use raw query instead

Thanks